# Kendo UI Grid passes null viewmodel to my Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

This is making me crazy, I used Kendo UI Grid in more than 6 projects now using the version 2013.1.514.340, I never had any issues but this morning I tried to use a newer version 2013.2.918.340 on a new project and I have a major issue.

With this new project I have a grid, nothing fancy.  What it does is represent a table in a database called LogTypes where  you can add, edit and delete items.  Retrieving the Data and the Delete Method works but the Create Method gives me null values

Here is a screenshot
[image]

Another funny thing is that the Update Method does not call the SaveOrUpdate at all.
Client side validation also works.

[image]

Here is my full code, I hope someone here can help me :(

**My View Models**

```
public class LogTypesPageViewModel
{
    public IList<LogTypesViewModel> LogTypes { get; set; }
}
public class LogTypesViewModel
{
    public int? LogTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LogTypeDescription { get; set; }

}
```

**My Controller**

```
public class LogTypesController : Controller
{
private readonly ILogTypesQuery logTypesQuery;
private readonly ICommandProcessor commandProcessor;

public LogTypesController(
    ILogTypesQuery logTypesQuery,
    ICommandProcessor commandProcessor)
{
    this.logTypesQuery = logTypesQuery;
    this.commandProcessor = commandProcessor;
}

public ActionResult Index()
{           
    var viewModel = new LogTypesPageViewModel
    {
        LogTypes = logTypesQuery.GetLogTypes()
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}

public ActionResult GetLogTypes([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var logTypes = logTypesQuery.GetLogTypes();
    var result = logTypes.ToDataSourceResult(request);

    return Json(result);
}

[HttpPost]
[Transaction]
public ActionResult SaveOrUpdate(LogTypesViewModel viewModel, [DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)

{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var command = new SaveOrUpdateLogTypeCommand(
                        viewModel.LogTypeId,
                        viewModel.LogTypeDescription
                        );

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            commandProcessor.Process(command);
            viewModel.LogTypeId = command.LogTypeId;
        }
    }

    var result = new[] { viewModel }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState);

    return Json(result);
}       

[HttpPost]
[Transaction]
public ActionResult Delete(int logTypeId, [DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var command = new DeleteLogTypeCommand(logTypeId);
    commandProcessor.Process(command);

    return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
}
```

**My View**

```
@model ViewModels.LogTypes.LogTypesPageViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log Types";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Log Types</h1>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.LogTypes)
    .Name("grid-log-types")
    .Columns(c =>
    {
        c.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Edit();
            commands.Destroy();
        }).Width(150);

        c.Bound(x => x.LogTypeDescription);
        c.Bound(x => x.LogTypeId);
    }) 
    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Create()) 
    .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))   
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Ajax()
        .Create(create => create.Action("SaveOrUpdate", "LogTypes"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("SaveOrUpdate", "LogTypes"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Delete", "LogTypes"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetLogTypes", "LogTypes"))
        .Model(x => x.Id(p => p.LogTypeId))
        )
)
```

Is there something wrong in what I am doing? Why doesn't it trigger the Update and why Create passes null value?

**UPDATE**

I also tried it like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ExternalUserManagement.Web.Mvc.Controllers.ViewModels.LogTypes.LogTypesViewModel>()
```

Still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! I missed the adding the reference to

> kendo.web.min.js

Comment: I had an issue where the editor value would not post within my viewmodel.  But, it would pass if I directory referenced the model itself.   Very frustrating because I try to always use viewmodels in my views.